# jQuery - changing border of specific row

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm loading a table and then after the table has loaded I want to put a border on two specific rows. They are always the same rows each time the table is loaded. The code I have below works but the default line breaks created between the table rows get in the way of putting a border anything less than 2px. Using a border of 2px for me is too heavy, but using a border of 1px doesn't show up over the default black line.

The code I'm using:

```
    $('#table-selections tr:eq(5)').css('border-bottom','2px dashed black');
    $('#table-selections tr:eq(5)').css('border-top','2px dashed black');
    $('#table-selections tr:eq(17)').css('border-bottom','2px dashed black');
```

It doesn't seem an elegant way to add a border and doesnt surpass the default lines between the rows.

edit:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dV95Q/)

showing that 1px doesn't work while 2px does

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: post edited with the fiddle

Comment: I think this is to do with border-collapse (see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dV95Q/28/)). Not convinced I know exactly what's going on, though, the behaviour does seem a bit strange. Guessing your 1px border is collapsing with the standard border, and the standard border is winning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting expected 1px border, because of css applied in each td(border top).

In bootstarp.min.css

```
.table thead > tr > th, .table tbody > tr > th, .table tfoot > tr > th, .table thead > tr > td, .table tbody > tr > td, .table tfoot > tr > td {
    border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

so you have to manually removed the boder top from 3rd row as

```
$('#table-selections tr:eq(2)').css('border-bottom', '1px dashed black');
$('#table-selections tr:eq(3) td').css('border-top', 'none');
$('#table-selections tr:eq(4)').css('border-top', '2px dashed black');
```

You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dV95Q/18/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use 2 different classes for the 2 types of border, and use `addClass` and `removeClass` in your jQuery script.

Does your css for the table contain `border: 2px !important;` ?

Comment: no, i tried that, and whilst using 2px worked, using 1px didnt do anything.

Comment: Maybe add !important to the style you add in your jquery script?

Comment: tried that also, something weird is happening lol: note, just added a small fiddle to demo the issue,

Answer (score 0):

Just add some `css`

```
.table-condensed tr{
    display:table;
    width:100%; 

}

.table-condensed td{
     width: 100px; 
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dV95Q/29/)